# CMake change list entry

Tags: cmake

I need to store a dynamic count of variables which fortunately can be referenced by an integer index. So I thought of a list variable holding them, so I could access each by its list index. So far so good: I can store them and retrieve their values. **But how can I change their values?**

The `insert` command creates a new element at the speficied position and a `set` or `change` keyword is not defined. Is this really the only or shortest way to e.g. increment the fourth element???

```
set(testlist "")
list(APPEND testlist 1)
list(APPEND testlist 2)
list(APPEND testlist 3)
list(APPEND testlist 4)
list(APPEND testlist 5)

message(${testlist})

# Here cometh the magic
list(GET testlist 3 tmp)
list(REMOVE_AT testlist 3)
math(EXPR tmp ${tmp}+1)
list(INSERT testlist 3 ${tmp})

message(${testlist})
```

Please tell me I'm wrong!